# Can't logout/sign out from Google using Spring

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, logout

Could somebody help me with logout from google?
I'm trying example for login and logout for my application from here: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/
I can't successfully logout, user is always logged in. I see that XSRF-TOKEN is still present in the cookies. I've tried various examples, but nothing works. Here is the original code https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2 and here is my attempt:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Map<String, Object> user(@AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User principal) {
        return Collections.singletonMap("name", principal.getAttribute("name"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.authorizeRequests(a -> a.antMatchers("/", "/error", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()).csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .exceptionHandling(e -> e.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)))

                .logout(l -> l.logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "XSRF-TOKEN").invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandler()))
                .oauth2Login();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }

    class LogoutSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

        @Override
        public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

            authentication.setAuthenticated(false);
            invalidateCurrentSession(request, response);
            super.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        }
    }

    private void invalidateCurrentSession(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse().saveToken(null, request, response);
        // session is anyway null
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
            request.getSession();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you able to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.